# Is a non-Jew who was Sandek in non-Orthodox brit allowed to be sandek again after conversion?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah

A few articles like [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandek) speak of a custom amongst non-religious groups allowing non-Jews, women, and otherwise to be sandek despite halacha or minhag. It happens whether unfortunate or not. But if 'birds of a feather flock together',and the non-Jew becomes a ger, would anything prohibit one from the honor again under Orthodox auspice?

Also, the question extends to a reform/conservative conversion where one is sandek and then converts up to Orthodox?

Comment: Would you accept "Yes, [widely accepted book on laws of _mila_] makes no mention of such a case and therefore doesn't prohibit it."? If not, there's probably something missing in your question (namely, your motivation for asking).

Comment: @msh210 Yes, I would. Motivation: I know of at least one maybe two cases of non-Jew pursuing gerut who was a sandek pre-Conversion. He didn't know any better at the time.

Comment: Why would he not be treated like any other ger tzedek who is asked to be a sandek after his convertsion?